# How To Create A Decryption Function For This RC4 Algorithm

Tags: asp.net, algorithm, function, encryption, vbscript

I pulled this code for ASP from http://personalsources.com/includes/functions.asp and its encode all password into RC4 , the function of encoding is :

```
function rc4(byref thestr, byref thekey)
  dim asciiarray(255)
  dim keyarray(255)
  if isnull(thestr) then exit function
  if len(thekey)=0 then exit function
  if len(thestr)=0 then thestr=" "
  if len(thestr)=0 then exit function
  zxlen=len(thekey)
  for ipos=0 To 255
    keyarray(ipos)=asc(mid(thekey, ((ipos) Mod (zxlen)) + 1, 1))
  next
  for ipos=0 To 255
    asciiarray(ipos)=ipos
  next
  vpos=0
  for ipos=0 To 255
    vpos=(vpos + asciiarray(ipos) + keyarray(ipos)) Mod 256
    tempa= asciiarray(ipos)
    asciiarray(ipos)=asciiarray(vpos)
    asciiarray(vpos)=tempa
  next
  ipos=0
  vpos=0
  for rcx=1 To len(thestr)
    ipos=(ipos + 1) Mod 256 
    vpos=(vpos + asciiarray(ipos)) Mod 256
    tempb=(asciiarray(ipos) + asciiarray(vpos)) Mod 256
    tempa=asciiarray(ipos)
    asciiarray(ipos)=asciiarray(vpos)
    asciiarray(vpos)=tempa
    tempc=asciiarray(tempb)
    rc4=rc4 & chr(asc(mid(thestr, rcx, 1)) xor tempc)
  next
end function
```

you know if we have the key of encryption (RC4) so we can decrypt the password very easily , but i dont know how this function encrypt password ? and what is the exact algorithm of this function ? is this possible to write a function to decrypt this RC4 password ?

---

for example a encryption password by this function is like this (and its never like RC4 passwords!!!) :

```
&gt;r&#178;&#231;&#197;&#197;
```

Comment: Thanks Travis , how do u find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC4 is a stream cypher, so it uses XOR to encrypt.  Running RC4 produces a random looking keystream of bytes.

To encrypt you do:

> plaintext XOR keystream -> cyphertext

To decrypt you do:

> cyphertext XOR keystream -> plaintext

In both cases the keystream is the same, produced from RC4 using the same key.

Answer (score 1):

The password isn't encrypted, so you can't decrypt it.

The data is encrypted. To decrypt it, you need the password, and run the same function with the encrypted text and the original password (the one that was used to encrypt it).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), all you have to do to decrypt RC4 is run the same function again with the same key.